# Multiple webviews in one UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, storyboard

Lets say I have a `UIViewController` with two buttons, both going (push) to another `UIViewController` that has two `UIWebViews` (showing two different PDF files), how can I make sure that only the one I choose via the button is showed?

Comment: Thanks to Andrew Sula and Ty_ is found prepareForSegue.
For others who are looking for this, this guide below was most helpful.
Thanks guys :)
http://nscookbook.com/2013/01/ios-programming-recipe-5-passing-values-between-segues-with-prepareforsegue/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass some information to the `UIViewController` which has the `UIWebViews`, saying which button was pressed. Then, based on that information, decide which of the `UIWebViews` to display.

As you are using storyboards, I suggest you look into `prepareForSegue`. It will allow you to set a property on the destination view controller with something like the following. You should add this to the `UIViewController` which contains the buttons.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"buttonOne"]) {
        ExampleViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.buttonClicked = @"One";
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"buttonTwo"]) {
        ExampleViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.buttonClicked = @"Two";
    }
}
```

You can then use the `buttonClicked` property in the destination view controller to decide which you should display. If you have two separate `UIWebViews`, you could choose to hide one using `webViewOne.hidden = YES;` and show the other using `webViewTwo.hidden = NO;`.

However, it would probably be neater to only have a single `UIWebView`. You could then use `prepareForSeque` to pass in the URL of the PDF you would like it to display, rather than just sending the name of the button clicked.

Comment: Sounds good.
The code you have written, is it going into the .m of the UIViewController containing the UIWebViews=?
How does 'prepareForSegue' know the difference between the buttons? Do I have to set a label or ID of some kind on the buttons?

Comment: This would go in the .m file for the `UIViewController` which has the buttons. `prepareForSegue` uses the `segue.identifier` to identify to segue triggered, which we want to identify the buttons in this example. Using Interface Builder, select each of the buttons' `push` segues and give them both a unique `identifier`.

Comment: Oh my, this sounds very nice and much more neat than what I'm doing now.
I will have a look at this later.
I guess that the @"One" and @"Two" are the names of the buttons I need to give as unique identifiers as you mention?
Where do I put in the different PDF files?

Comment: They are the names of the identifiers for the segues. They can called anything (any string at least) as long as they match the identifiers given in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you `webView` is in a view controller called `SecondViewController` and your buttons are in the view controller called `FirstViewController`

**1) Create an object in your `SecondViewController.h`**

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *whichButtonClicked;

@end
```

**2) Import `SecondViewController` in your `FirstViewController`**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
```

**3) In you button IBAction method in `FirstViewController.m` . use this code**

```
 - (IBAction) firstButtonClicked
{
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondView"];
secondViewController. whichButtonClicked = @"first"
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}

 - (IBAction) secondButtonClicked
{
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondView"];
secondViewController. whichButtonClicked = @"second"
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}
```

*PS Don't forget. In you `Storyboard`. Set `Storyboard ID` for SecondViewController as `secondView`*

**4) In your `SecondViewController.m` use this code to check which button**

```
if ([self.whichButtonClicked isEqualToString:@"first"])
{
///display first web view here
}
else
{
//display second web view here
}
```

Hope this helps